# Svelte: Unable to get imported unused CSS purged

Tags: svelte, rollup-plugin-postcss

I unsuccessfully tried to remove unused css imported from an external css file.

I have tried a lot of combinaisons in vain, every time I run the build script I end up with a huge *bundle.css*.

Here is the list of everything I tried so far:

- Importing the file from App.svelte `<script>`
- Importing the file from App.svelte `<style>` (using [postcss-import](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-import))
- Importing the file directly from main.js
- Using [postcss-purgecss](https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss) along with [rollup-plugin-postcss](https://github.com/egoist/rollup-plugin-postcss) instead of passing by [svelte-preprocess](http://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess)

I am pretty sure there is something I am doing wrong but I honestly cannot figure out what.

If anyone have a clue on how to resolve this I would love to hear some feedback.

Simple repo example: https://github.com/mgrisole/svelte-playground

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to follow these steps:

1. Import `rollup-plugin-postcss` in `rollup.config.js`:

```
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
```

2. Replace relevant section (lines 41-56 of your `rollup.config.js`) with:

```
svelte({
  preprocess: sveltePreprocess({ postcss: true }),
  compilerOptions: {
    dev: !production,
    css: css => { css.write('bundle.css') },
  },
  ...(production && { emitCss: false }),
}),
production
  ? postcss({ extract: true, minimize: true })
  : css({ output: 'bundle.css' }),
```

2. Configure purgecss in `postcss.config.js`:

```
const purgecss = require('@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss')({
  content: ['./**/**/*.html', './**/**/*.svelte'],
  whitelistPatterns: [/svelte-/],
  defaultExtractor: content => content.match(/[\w-/:]+(?<!:)/g) || []
});

const isProduction = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH && !process.env.LIVERELOAD

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    ...(isProduction ? [purgecss] : [])
  ]
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply, unfortunately I end up with a nearly empty bundle.css after executing the build script.
I created a branch following your suggestions, do you know if I omitted something: https://github.com/mgrisole/svelte-playground/tree/alternative-conf

Comment: You should remove or comment out `css({ output: 'bundle.css' })` (line 56). This is handled now in line 52, which runs only on dev mode.

Comment: Indeed, that was so obvious, thank so much mutil for your precious help!

Comment: I think we should change whitelistPatterns to safelist it seems like it has been changed since v3 https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss/releases/tag/v3.0.0
It seems however that it is not needed, if I remove the exception svelte's selectors are not being removed. It surely need more investigation on my side though.